# URL gets updated when using transition.abort() on using browser back

Tags: ember.js

I am a newbie to ember and sorry if this question has been already asked. I was just trying to prompt an alert when the user leaves the login form. Everything works fine when i use linkTo but i when i use browsers back or update the url manually the url gets updated eventhough the transition has been aborted.
I just tried with this

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uwenet/3/edit)

I logged the currentPath in ApplicationController.

I am not sure what am i going wrong. Please suggest

Answer (score 5):

I got around this by using window.history.forward()

You can see it's compatibility at http://caniuse.com/#search=history

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    actions: {
      willTransition: (transition) {
         transition.abort();

         if (window.history) {
           window.history.forward();
         }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected, when manually changing the URL/pressing the back button, the URL changes before the abort can be called, this causes the URL to be temporarily out of sync with what's on the page. 
I remember machty mentioning there is not a simple way to fix this, and it is fixed the next time any navigation is done anyway.